# Removing the background of a postcard scan

Tags: image-processing, background-subtraction

I'm trying to build a tool to automatically create a "background mask" of a scan of a postcard, allowing pixel information not relating to the postcard itself (ie. the ceiling of the scanner) to be transparent.

The attempts I've made so far have been wildly imprecise (often finding regions of transparency where it's logically impossible for a postcard to have holes), but the  computer vision module of my physics degree is ancient enough that I'm struggling to form an approach to achieve this reliably. How should I approach this challenge?

Aspects I've considered, but don't know how to turn into an algorithm:

- The front & back are mirror images and should have very close to equivalent masks
- I can add coloured backdrops to my scans if needed (though I need to be able to scan poscards in full colour — I've found chroma-keying too error-prone so far)
- I can assume my postcards are all broadly rectangular; ie. no holes & 4 sides — though not necessarily straight edges
- I know the edges of the postcard are going to be within a narrow border around the edge of the image (cropped at scan time)

I've been working with scans at 600dpi (with postcards normally at 10cm x 14cm)

---

Here are some examples of an old postcard I've scanned.

An example front of a postcard:
[image]

An example back of the same postcard:
[image]

Example non-straight edged (though I've manually whited out the background on this one)
[image]